# C/C++ app to view Wireshark Reset packets

Tags: c++, c, windows, wireshark

Is it possible to view, in real time any Reset (RST) packets sent out to the remote (source) IP from the Local (destination) IP on the machine in which the source code is running?

We are looking to obtain the remote ip address where a RST packet has been sent to from the local machine.

This is the required into in Wireshark:
[image]

Have been looking at netstat and GetIpStatistics. But neither of these work.

Any ideas(Windows based from C/C++ code)?

Comment: Wireshark on Windows uses WinPcap (equivalent to Linux libpcap) to actually handle the packet capture. Can you use that?

Comment: Isn't that what Wireshark is for? Why do you want another application to do that?

Comment: We are using the IPs it finds in our app. Wireshark is useful for a manual task but not to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible in real time to do what you want. If Wireshark is able to do it, then you can also do it.

You may want to take a look at libpcap, a portable C library for packet capture. The information about libpcap can be obtained from it's home page at http://www.tcpdump.org/. You then need to do some additional processing for the captured packets:

- See if the packet is long enough to have all the required data (this check needs to be done layer-by-layer in separate parts)
- See if the Ethernet source address is the address of the Ethernet adapter in the computer (so that it's a sent packet, not a received packet)
- See if it's an IP packet using the EtherType header field
- See if the IP source address of the packet is the address of the interface in the computer
- See if it's a TCP packet
- See if it contains the TCP flag RST
- You may want to check also IP-level and TCP-level checksums
- Extract the remote IP address

The most common Ethernet framing type is the Ethernet II frame explained in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Ethernet_II. The IP header can be parsed using the instructions in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791. The TCP header can be parsed using the instructions in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt. So, in summary: you need to capture raw packets using libpcap and be prepared to parse them at all protocol levels.

A competent programmer familiar with network programming should be able to do this in a day, but I would reserve more time for this if you're not familiar with network programming.

I'm not aware of any shortcut. Obviously you could try some script hacks around tcpdump, but they would be very hackish and if you're running on Windows they may not be possible.